# MIPS 32 lb instruction with offset

Tags: assembly, mips32

I don't understand the solution given for a previous homework problem.
Question: Show the contents of `$R3` after the following instruction is executed.

```
lb $R3, 13($R2)
```

Initial values:

```
$R2 = 12(decimal)
$R3 = 14(decimal)
```

Initial Memory Address(Decimal) -- Content(decimal):

```
36 -- -18
32 -- 99
28 -- 177
24 -- -14
```

Solution:

```
$R3 = OxFFFFFFFF
```

I don't understand how he arrived at that answer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That takes r2 (12) adds 13 making it 25 (decimal) and reads the byte from that address yes?  And maybe they assume that the reset of memory is initialized to 0xFF.  And does lb sign extend?

Comment: lb is sign extended. so if memory 24 is -14 that means the first byte is 11111111 and the second byte (address 25) is also 11111111 which is 0xFF. sign extended brings it to 0xFFFFFFFF? Is that the right way to do it?  Thank you so much for replying!!

Comment: In MIPS the memory hold a 32-bit word. the most significant bit is stored in the lowest address. So byte 25 is the second byte in the 32 bit version of address 24. And that's why the mem addresses are staggered in multiples of 4, 1 for each byte. I think.

Comment: sorry, but the mips32 code lb means load byte. Thanks for your explanation, that solves it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google mips instruction set you see that lb is load byte.

```
lb $t, offset($s)
```

means

```
$t = MEM[$s + offset]; advance_pc (4);
```

assuming MEM is 32 bits wide here, but that is at the edge of the core, how it is implemented we dont care about.

The definitions you have first being decimal which may have been intentional to create learning pain.  Then are all can fit in a byte sized values which could imply byte addresses.

r2 is 12 then we add 13 to get decimal address 25 which is not defined.  If we go with the notion as you mention in comments that these are word sized definitions.  Then 24 = -14 means at address 0x18 (which BTW is a valid 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit and 64 bit aligned address) we have the value 0xFFFFFFF2 for address 0x18, we are after 0x19.  So depending on the endianness that could be the 0xooFFoooo byte or 0xooooFFoo byte in either case that is an 0xFF.

Then you need to know that lb sign extends.  The msbit of 0xFF is a one so the rest of the bits will be ones we load 0xooooooFF and then sign extend that to 0xFFFFFFFF.  Then save that in r3. (and increment the program counter to the next instruction).

Looking at this the other way, since you gave us the answer of 0xFFFFFFFF, that is not a byte value so lb must be sign extending and the value read must have been 0xFF.  If it didnt sign extend we would expect 0x000000XX where XX is the byte we are looking for.  And or xx is positive from a byte sized twos complement perspective and then it wouldnt be obvious there was a sign extension.

The initial value of r3 is not relevant, just there to possibly trip you up.